# How do I define a nested Pydantic model with a Tuple containing Optional models?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am currently working with following nested model (FinalModel):

```
class Model1(BaseModel):
    count: int

class Model2(BaseModel):
    method: str
    selector: dict
    count: int

class FinalModel(BaseModel):
    slow: bool
    models: Tuple[
        Optional[Model1],
        Optional[Model2],
    ]]
```

I am expecting the Tuple to have a variable length since I'd like to pass in either Model1 or Model2 or both based on the requirements. However, the tuple seems to be expecting a fixed length of 2.

Please note that Union is not an option for me since I expect number of models to increase in future and the possible combinations will increase as well.

Answer (score 2):

To specify a variable-length tuple of multiple types you can use ellipsis literal `...` and `Union`, like below:

```
class FinalModel(BaseModel):
    slow: bool
    models: Tuple[Union[Model2, Model1], ...]
```

When using `Union` one also need to keep in mind [that](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions):

> However, as can be seen above, `pydantic` will attempt to 'match' any of the types defined under `Union` and will use the first one that matches.[...]
>
> As such, it is recommended that, when defining `Union` annotations, **the most specific type is included first and followed by less specific types**.

Therefore, for your example, `Model2` must precede `Model1` in `Union`, since the objects of `Model2` when parsing will match with `Model1`, and the other members will be discarded. Or [use](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/) `extra = forbid`.

```
class Model1(BaseModel):
    count: int

    class Config:
        extra = "forbid"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are  you sure you want to use a tuple? A tuple is fixed size in its nature, using it in you Pydantic model will require both elements to be present.

Instead, you could use a `List[Union[Model1, Model2]]`

Comment: That works as well. I ended up using Tuple itself. As suggested by Eric Jolibois on github,  `Tuple[Union[Model1, Model2],...]`